# multiple database access from one application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on a C# application with SQL Server 2008. I have two different databases. I will be selecting the database name from the drop down list at login time.

When I'm inserting 5 rows into the table, that time 3 rows are inserted in the table of the database which I have selected at login time and 2 rows are inserted in another database.

We've checked the connection string and it is correct and it takes the selected database.

So here I am not understanding why database is changing at insertion time.

This is my insertion code.

```
        SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        _con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into " + Tablename + "(" + ColumnNames + ")" + " values (" + Values + ")", _con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _con.Close();
        Dtb = "";
```

Here is the example about problem.

I am accessing application and doing interaction with database 'A' from one system.
same time I am accessing application and doing interaction with database 'B' from another system.

That time data is overloading like this A <-> B.
Means data from A is reflecting to B.(Nw both database is logged in application.)

Comment: You will need to post some code.

Comment: also, are you referring to the server is changing or a catalog is changing?

Make sure you do not have a "use DataBaseB;" anywhere in your sql.

Comment: This sounds pretty strange, show the Insert code.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to create a connection instance ( like new sqlconnection) for each insertion. better loop 3 insertions with a same connection string/variable you already created.